# Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm in IBM Q Experience

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

I have composed the gate with IBM Q Experience, but I do not know how to set the answer.
Please tell me how to set it?

Comment: What do you mean by answer? Do you mean a measurement? Please add a figure of your circuit or QASM code to better understand what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help:

```
circuit.measure([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

for 4 qubits.

The secret number = '1001' for the circuit below:

**NOTE** the xor gates "cx" in qbit 0 and 3 are because it is 1 on the first and last bit of the secret number.

[image]

And after that simulate (to get the answer):

[image]

I hope I've helped.